# How to make Docker to avoid V1 registry

Tags: configuration, docker, version, docker-registry

Docker versions 1.6 and above use the Docker Registry V2 API however it is still liable to make requests looking for an old V1 registry. I think I saw there is a configuration option to make Docker avoid making any /v1/ requests.

I saw this option very recently but now I can't find it. I suspect it was in a page linked to by the Docker email that told us the Registry will stop supporting Docker versions prior to 1.6

I know Docker only looks for a V1 registry when it has no luck looking for /v2 but I want to stop it altogether. How can I stop Docker making requests to /v1/ registry URLs under any circumstances ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`--disable-legacy-registry`

> "prevents the docker daemon from pull, push, and login operations against v1 registries." - 
>   [Source](https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#interacting-with-v1-registries)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10234875)

Comment: The OP asked for the name of the option and the link to find it.

Comment: Michael, thank you for that. Do you know if it's new in version 1.9 or if I should expect to find it in older versions ? Docker 1.8.2 fails to start when I add it as a parameter.

Comment: It's in Docker 1.8.2, you can see the option on the list: `docker daemon --help`   How are you adding the parameter?

Comment: My start command is in a file named: /etc/systemd/system/docker.service.d/execStart.conf  I edited that file to add the parameter. Thus making it contain:

Comment: [Service]
ExecStart=
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker daemon --disable-legacy-registry -H fd://

Comment: with this parameter Docker fails to start. Job for docker.service failed. See 'systemctl status docker.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.

Comment: @michael I tried your suggestion  docker daemon --help and I thought I saw the --disable-legacy-registry option. I must have been dreaming. When I do docker daemon --help  now, this option is not amongst those listed. docker version shows I am using version 1.8.2

Comment: The page at [link](https://fossies.org/diffs/docker/1.8.2_vs_1.8.3/docs/reference/commandline/daemon.md-diff.html) suggests that option --disable-legacy-registry did not arrive until version 1.8.3

Comment: This [link](https://docs.docker.com/engine/misc/deprecated/#interacting-with-v1-registries) suggests it arrived in version 1.9

Comment: I think I trust the [release note](https://github.com/docker/docker/releases/tag/v1.8.3) which says it was new in version 1.8.3

Comment: @Michael your link says "Sorry, we can't find that page".. seems like Bruce P was right in the first place too remind you to add the essential parts of the source.